# React - Import dynamically path to pdf file

Tags: reactjs, import, require

Firstly, my page will make an http request to an API

API then response an object which have a `path: ./assets/sample.pdf`

I want to get `urlPdf` from `import urlPdf from response.path`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh super simple. Just `const result = require(response.path)`

Comment: Since file-loader has been upgraded from v1 to v6, now it should be `require(response.path).default;`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

const App = () => {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState();
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState();
  const [urlPdf, setUrlPdf] = useState();

  const _onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => setNumPages(numPages);
  
  const fetchPdfPath = ({
    // logic handle get path...
    // setUrlPdf(response.data);
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      {urlPdf && (
        <Document
          file={urlPdf}
          onLoadSuccess={_onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
      )}
      <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer